# Increase the height of anchor tag in td element

Tags: html, css

Table td with 'a' tag,need to increase the height.

```
<td width="200"  valign="middle" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif ; font-size:15px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;background-color:#17528b;">
                                                    <a href="${url}verify-user/${emailString}" target="_blank"  style="color:#ffffff; padding-bottom: 2000px;text-decoration:none;display:block;line-height:34px;">CREATE PASSWORD</a>
                                                </td>
```

I need increase the the height a  bit more as it looks very small .

Comment: Height of text? Or height of line? Or height of element?

Comment: I would suggest putting all your styling in a separate file and including it in your html

Comment: either text or element,i jst need it to look big ,pleae help

Comment: Tell clearly what you want

Comment: Just add ```font-size:1.5em``` and then see what happens

Comment: can you upload your query on jsbin

Comment: didnt work,actually i am trying to send an email and this code is for a create password link,now the anchor tag is a bit small i need a bit bigger one in height like a big square ,right now it looks like a small square

Comment: i dont have any jquery or JS for this its simple view page with table elements and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change font size give font size `font-size:30px`
Else if you want to change element give padding `padding:40px`
Else if you want to change the height of the text `line-height:20px`

Comment: adding the padding 10px in the element td worked for me,Thank you @lavanya E

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can adjust it

```
 <style>
   #create-account
   {
   display:block; 
   padding:15px 15px; //you can adjust  (top/bottom)px   (left/right)px
   color:#ffffff; 
   text-decoration:none;
   margin:5px 5px; //you can adjust
   font-size: 1.2rem;  //you can adjust
   }
 </style>   



  <a href="${url}verify-user/${emailString}" target="_blank" id="create-account">CREATE PASSWORD</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to increase the height of the td table cell or a tag, put these into the css section of the td or a tag :

```
display : inline-block; height : <what you want for height comes here>
```

hope it helps you